# Review queue Help Center draft: Triage queue

Tags: discussion, product-discovery, announcement, help-center-proposed

This post is part of a larger effort to [create Help Center pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356120/creating-new-help-center-documents-for-review-queues-project-overview) for each of the Review queues. You can learn more about this project in the overview post. These posts will be locked so that everyone has a chance to review each original draft and provide feedback in the answers. We will continue to collect feedback until **November 9th, 2020**.

We are looking for your feedback on this draft for the **Triage queue**.
When reviewing this draft please consider the following:

- What is essential to know about using this queue?
- Is there any information that’s missing or should be removed?

> ## How do I use the Triage queue?
>
> *Access earned at 500 reputation*
> Potentially-problematic questions get
> added to this queue in order to be appropriately categorised and
> routed for further consideration.  Before reviewing in this queue, you
> should be familiar with what sorts of questions should and should not
> be closed. To find that information, see the following two pages:
>
> - [Closed question help article](/help/closed-questions) is a
>   network-wide guide for the primary reasons questions should be closed.
>   This generally happens when a question:
>
>   - is a duplicate of an existing question on the site
>   - needs additional details or clarity to be answered
>   - needs to be focused as the existing question is too broad.
>   - is an opinion-based question that doesn’t have an objectively correct answer.
> - [On topic article](/help/on-topic) is a site-specific guide to
>   what types of questions are on and off topic on this site. This page
>   will differ on each site on the Network.
>
> ### Basic workflow
>
> - Choose **Looks OK** if the question is good as-is and should not be closed as a duplicate. Read the comments for any
>   context.
> - **Needs community edit** if the question is clear and on-topic
>   but could use some editing help to improve grammar, spelling, or
>   formatting
> - **Flag** questions that cannot or should not be answered due to
>   being spam or needing to be closed.
> - Choose **Needs author edit** if the
>   question is incomplete or requires clarification from the post author; this will flag the post for closure.
> - **Skip** the task if you’re uncertain. This is the default action in this queue. There is no
>   penalty to skipping a task. When you skip the task, the question
>   immediately becomes available for others to review.
>
> Some of the content of this page is adapted from information in our
> [Meta Stack Overflow FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/how-does-the-triage-review-queue-work), which also contains more in-depth
> guidance if you are interested in reading more about this queue.

### Other drafts

To review other drafts in part of this project, please see below:

- [Review queue Help Center draft: Close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356121/review-queue-help-center-draft-close-votes)
- [Review queue Help Center draft: Reopen votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356126/review-queue-help-center-draft-reopen-votes-queue)
- [Review queue Help Center draft: Low-quality posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356127/review-queue-help-center-draft-low-quality-posts-queue)
- [Review queue Help Center draft: Suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356125/review-queue-help-center-draft-suggested-edits-queue)
- [Review queue Help Center draft: First posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356122/review-queue-help-center-draft-first-posts-queue)
- [Review queue Help Center draft: Late answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356123/review-queue-help-center-draft-late-answers-queue)

Stack Overflow only:

- Review queue Help Center draft: Triage (this post)
- [Review queue Help Center draft: Help & improvement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402612/review-queue-help-center-draft-help-improvement-queue)

Comment: I find it a bit confusing that two buttons leads to the flag dialog, just different levels. If you decide to keep them both, I think more emphasis needs to go into that, as the dialog can be very confusing to beginners with the many different options and currently also no indication of which options opens up a new dialog.

Comment: An explanation of how questions get added to this queue would help me understand why this queue exists and how I should use it.  It is by far the least obvious review queue to me, which is why I completely avoid it.  If the explanation is too detailed, then a link to another help page would suffice.

Comment: I think the importance of [How does the Triage review queue work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/how-does-the-triage-review-queue-work) is being _massively_ understated by providing a link at the end of the article in more of a footnote and it would be of great benefit to emphasize the amount of guidance it can provide and how important it is to read it prior to using the queue.

Comment: @Catija , Lisa: How do you prefer that I format the suggested edits? Especially the minor ones, such as typos, punctuation, etc. My choice, used in the answer below, was *"Change from: <original, quoted> to: <new, quoted>"*. It does not look as easy to see changes as it could have been, in retrospect...

Comment: @TimurShtatland I often will put the changed content edit in bold or italics to draw attention to it but having the two versions near each other saves us a lot of scrolling :D

Answer (score 19):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

> Choose **Needs author edit** if the question is incomplete or requires clarification from the post author this will flag the post for closure.

That's a [run-on sentence](https://academicguides.waldenu.edu/writingcenter/grammar/runonsentences). This should be changed to one of the following:

- "Choose **Needs author edit** if the question is incomplete or requires clarification from the post author. This will flag the post for closure."
- "Choose **Needs author edit** if the question is incomplete or requires clarification from the post author; this will flag the post for closure."
- "Choose **Needs author edit** if the question is incomplete or requires clarification from the post author, to flag the post for closure."

Comment: Your first alternative is the clearest to understand, I think.

Comment: Catija's fixed this in the draft in the question using a semicolon.

Answer (score 5):

I personally am not sure that the "Looks Okay" language is strong enough to indicate that the question should be free of any problems. My suggestion is maybe edit it to the following (emphasis added here to highlight the difference from the original language, not to suggest emphasis should be added to the final edit):

> Choose Looks OK if the question is good as-is. **That is, it should not be closed, is on-topic,** and **is not** a duplicate. Read the comments for any context.

I'm sure someone could word this better. But hopefully you catch what I'm trying to get at.

My reasoning for suggesting this language instead is to minimize the chance that someone gets confused here, and think that we're asking them about how they generally feel about the question. This makes it more clear that we want them to compare the question to the aforementioned standards for closure.

Comment: Thoughts on this: "*- Choose **Looks OK** if the question is answerable as-is and does not need to be edited, closed or deleted. Read the comments for any context.*" One of the major purposes is to catch things that need editing, so not mentioning that seems like we're missing out a big element.

Comment: I like that. That works too.

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I suggest these minor typos / punctuation changes:

Change from:

> This generally happens when a question: is duplicate of an existing
> question on the site needs additional details or clarity to be
> answered needs to be focused as the existing question is too broad. is
> an opinion-based question that doesn’t have an objectively correct
> answer.

To:

> This generally happens when a question: is a duplicate of an existing
> question on the site **or** needs additional details or clarity to be
> answered **or** needs to be focused as the existing question is too
> broad **or** is an opinion-based question that doesn’t have an
> objectively correct answer.

Change from:

> There is no penalty to skipping a task. When you skip the task the
> question immediately becomes available for others to review.

to:

> There is no penalty for skipping a task. When you skip the task, the
> question immediately becomes available for others to review.

Change from:

> ... which also contains more in-depth guidance if you are interested
> in reading more about this queue.

to:

> ... which also contains more in-depth guidance, if you are interested
> in reading more about this queue.

Comment: I think the first one was perhaps Lisa copying content that was formatted at the source but lost its formatting... I expect it was already in an unordered list format.

Comment: @TylerH Yep. We compiled them in a Google Doc and the formatting got mucked up when we brought it into MD. :)

Comment: @Catija One change that remains in the first even with appropriate formatting is the missing *"a"* in front of duplicate

Comment: @Nick now fixed

Comment: @Catija Suggestion for next time: use Jupyter, which provides collaborative Markdown editing. (Though it requires setting up a local server.)

Answer (score -5):

Content suggestions

1. "if you’re uncertain" does not convey the spirit of reviewing (how uncertain should I be to click "skip"?) - skip should be the option of choice when doing Triage (I learned that the hard way myself), it should be "in case of any doubt" or something along the lines.

Editorial changes<sup>0</sup>

2. from "added to this queue **in order** to be" to "add to the queue to be" ("in order" is redundant, "this" refers to a known queue).
3. from "this page **will** differ" to "this page differs" (tense shift does not convey extra info).
4. from "**appropriately** categorised and routed" to "categorized and routed" (the categorization must be appropriate).
5. from "Before reviewing **in this queue**" to "before reviewing" (it is known that the page is about the triage queue).
6. from "see **the following two pages**:" to "see:" (what follows is obviously a list of pages).
7. "This is the default action **in this queue**" can be made actionable: "This should be your default action" (note that "in this queue" is redundant).

---

<sup>0</sup> See the quick reference on [prolixity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbosity).

Comment: I think that, while the more verbose phrasing might *officially* be redundant, it actually aids the overall readability, rather than adding clutter that hinders understanding.

Comment: @zcoop98 - I am not really sure how pleonasms help readability and understanding of rules that are important to grasp as easily as possible (none mentioned above bears an extra meaning - I thought we should strive to be as clear and concise as possible ). That said, these are just the suggestions (seems like they will be rejected) I think could benefit the help center page.