# Review queue Help Center draft: Help & improvement queue

Tags: discussion, product-discovery, announcement, help-center-proposed

This post is part of a larger effort to [create Help Center pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356120/creating-new-help-center-documents-for-review-queues-project-overview) for each of the Review queues. You can learn more about this project in the overview post. These posts will be locked so that everyone has a chance to review each original draft and provide feedback in the answers. We will continue to collect feedback until **November 9th, 2020**.

We are looking for your feedback on this draft for the **Help & improvement queue**.
When reviewing this draft please consider the following:

- What is essential to know about using this queue?
- Is there any information that’s missing or should be removed?

> ## How do I use the Help & improvement queue?
>
> *Access earned at 2,000 reputation*
> The Help and improvement queue
> includes questions that could use some assistance with grammar,
> spelling, or formatting issues. They may also need an improved title
> or need to have tags added or removed. You should be able to improve
> these posts without input from the question author.
>
> ### Basic workflow
>
> First, determine that this question is salvageable without
> clarification from the post-author. If the question is incomplete,
> unclear, or should be closed for any other reason, it should be closed
> rather than edited. When editing, remember to leave an explanatory
> edit description to help the question author understand your changes.
> Once you’ve reviewed the post decide which action to take.
>
> - **Edit** if the post is good quality but you can improve the post to make it better. Avoid editing posts that should be closed or deleted.
> - Choose **question is very low quality** if the post cannot be improved without input from the question author.
> - **Skip** if you’re uncertain about how you could improve the post – this is a good choice if you’re not familiar with the subject.
>
> For more information on how to edit effectively, please see our [Help Center article about editing](/help/editing).

### Other drafts

To review other drafts in part of this project, please see below:

- [Review queue Help Center draft: Close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356121/review-queue-help-center-draft-close-votes)
- [Review queue Help Center draft: Reopen votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356126/review-queue-help-center-draft-reopen-votes-queue)
- [Review queue Help Center draft: Low-quality posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356127/review-queue-help-center-draft-low-quality-posts-queue)
- [Review queue Help Center draft: Suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356125/review-queue-help-center-draft-suggested-edits-queue)
- [Review queue Help Center draft: First posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356122/review-queue-help-center-draft-first-posts-queue)
- [Review queue Help Center draft: Late answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356123/review-queue-help-center-draft-late-answers-queue)

Stack Overflow only:

- [Review queue Help Center draft: Triage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402611/review-queue-help-center-draft-triage-queue)
- Review queue Help Center draft: Help & improvement (this post)

Comment: Minor wording thing: "leave an explanatory edit description to help" Other places (including the edit screen) call it an edit summary. I fear that if we're not consistent in wording, editors may add text to the question in the form of "**EDIT 13**: edited for grammar", which I think we can all do without.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Understood. I guess "edit description" won't be noticed as the actual field when editing? Ah, it's technically "edit summary" - would that be better or are you suggesting we try to explicitly state "in the edit summary field" ?

Comment: @Catija I was thinking using the word "summary" would subtly steer people toward the correct field. But subtlety does not seem to work for everyone, so perhaps the explicit statement might be better :).

Comment: Should the sentences in the bulleted list all end in periods? It seems visually inconsistent to me to end only some and not others.

Comment: Minor suggestion - in "please see our Help Center article about editing", right now, only the word "Help" links to [this page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/editing). Instead, the whole phrase "Help Center article about editing" should be part of the linked text - i.e. `please see our [Help Center article about editing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/editing)`, or something similar to that.

Comment: Seems it has been empty for some time now, is it broken? https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/history

Answer (score 15):

One of my main pet peeves with the Help & Improvement queue is the *Question is very low quality* button.

> Choose question is very low quality if the post cannot be improved without input from the question author

That's wrong. These questions should be flagged to be closed. What it should read is:

> Navigate to the post, then either vote to close or flag to close if the post cannot be improved without input from the question author. Never ever choose question is very low quality, even though there is a large button for it and you need to navigate to the post to flag it properly.

See answers like [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260816/7296893) and [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357344/7296893) for some context on when the very low quality flag is appropriate. It boils down to: pretty much never.

This really is a problem of the queue and not the help section, but the help section should advise people properly nonetheless. My 3 most recent disputed flags are all VLQ flags on unsalvageable questions coming through H&I, and all these questions are now deleted. With the current help  guidance, the action was appropriate, but these really should've been close votes.

The workflow with VLQ flags from H&I is leading to a very counter-intuitive user experience, leading to misunderstanding of when to flag as VLQ and disputed flags. To add insult to injury, these don't count as completed reviews, and H&I is usually full of questions that should've been closed, leading to very few completed reviews.

For me, not understanding this properly initially led to only a single completed H&I review item and a couple of disputed VLQ flags on posts that did get closed and eventually deleted, which caused me to never review H&I again.

Comment: Why are you not suggesting that they just change the button to an actual "Flag / Close" button that opens up the dialog? :)

Comment: @Scratte There are plenty of feature requests to improve H&I. Adding close buttons would be a duplicate of [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289998/7296893), which in turn got marked as a duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288385/7296893) somehow. There are plenty of posts out there on H&I, why it's broken and why it needs to be improved, I'm just trying to prevent guidance in the help section that will lead to users being confused on what the VLQ flag is for and why they got disputed flags.

Comment: Telling people to open the post in a new tab is too complex for what should be a basic Help Center page. There are changes coming soon that will make this moot, so, while I appreciate and agree with this, we're going to leave the text as it is.

Comment: @Catija Then you will be telling people to use the wrong flag. If you want to keep it simple, just state _Never ever choose question is very low quality_, then they won't have a clue what to do with closeable questions but at least you won't be telling them to do the wrong thing.

Comment: There is a userscript (SOUP, I think) that adds a "close" button (linky-style, under the post) in the H&I queue. However, using this does *not* mark your review as "done" ... maybe the "changes coming" that Catija alludes to will fix that (i.e. actually have a fully-fledged "Close" button/option in the queue). I sure hope so!

Comment: @ErikA Just so you're aware, the team did indicate earlier this year that they were planning on changing that option. I [proposed a modification to it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/346929/377214), which I think is the one that's going to be implemented.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest 1 small change:
Change from: *post-author* to *post author*.